# Proper Front-End -Development Environment SetUp?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, frontend, development-environment, web-frontend

I'm a longtime lurker but new user hoping to get a little help! I apologise if this has been posted before, but I have been searching and found no answers as yet!

I have been a Front-End Developer for a few years, but self taught and something that I've fallen out of the loop with is the proper setup for a front end development environment in terms of folder structure.

Is there a best practice for setting up a web dev environment?

If it helps, I will mostly be using Bootstrap.

If this question isn't specific enough please do let me know and I will try to elaborate more!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tools you are familiar with. I'd suggest XAMPP as a local server, VS code as a text editor (they have a built-in extension very helpful for bootstrap, Emmet), that's pretty it, you'll probably need to configure PHP as well. The rest is more about what you want to use, rather than need.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! Sorry, maybe I worded the title badly, I was hoping more for direction on how to set up the folder structure like

Site
|_assets
      |_img
      |_css
      |_js
|
|_dist
      |_css
      |_js
|
|_index.html
|
|_package.json

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow and that previous comment did not format very well so I shall try and explain another way! I was hoping more for direction on how to set up the folder structure of the site like do I create a src folder that contains all the files of my site that will be public e.g. index.html and my 'dist' folder that contains minified css and js etc. And then keep things like node_modules  and my assets folder that contains un-minified css files, outside of that src folder?

Comment: I am not experienced in node, but usually, I have the "public_html" folder in which I store all the components including index.php or index.html, css and js files. Outside this folder, there are only .htaccess, robots.txt and other system files.

Comment: Just search for a frontend starter (its better if you know what technologies you want to start with ). e. g https://github.com/kdchang/frontend-starter-kit

Comment: Nowadays most of the front end work seems to be handled with frameworks, such as Angular, which do most of the structural setup for you while generating the project.